# php sort by array key

Tags: php, sorting

There are a bunch of topics on this but none of them are exactly what I need. I have an array with fname, lname, etc. I need to sort by lname using this code:

```
if ($myvar)

   foreach( $myvar as $key => $row) {

     echo "<p>$row->fname $row->lname";
     echo "$row->intro</p>";

     sort($row->lname);

    } else 

  echo "<p>No Results for your search.</p>";
```

You can see I threw in a sort, I've also tried ksort but nothing is happening. I tried a couple of other things from this forum, but no luck. Is the order wrong? Is the syntax incorrect?

My knowledge on this is limited, I thought it would be easier to do! :) Please advise if you can.

Comment: wahat is your input and output??? paste it here

Comment: usort() is the function you're looking for

Comment: If you are retrieving the data from a database, IE populating the array from database records, would it not make more sense to alphabetically order the results within the database query?

Comment: sort will only accept array input . I think you are passing string or int not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usort($myvar, function($a,$b) {return strcmp($a->lname, $b->lname);});
```

Though, as said in the comments, if this is searching over a database or search engine, you're better off letting those sort your stuff.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to sort from the query, as that sounds better. Do I sort from the query or directly in the db? Sorry if that question sounds dumb. I'm still learning.

Comment: the query should sort, e.g. in sql something like this `select fname,lname from _tablename_ order by lname`

Answer (score 0):

In your code seems like you have an array of arrays.
If you have only one array, you dont need use sort inside the foreach.
Sort - Sort an array, so use it directly like this:

```
if ($myvar) {
   uasort($myvar, function($a,$b) {return strcmp($a->lname, $b->lname);}));
}else{
    echo "<p>No Results for your search.</p>";
}
```